# cordova: app form to PDF

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, phonegap-plugins, phonegap

I've got a Cordova (Phonegap Build) app that provides a form for users to fill out. They then print (or print to PDF) and send me the PDF. **The problem is** that the data entered in the form does not render in the PDF - instead each field is empty in the PDF. I've tried many methods that have been outlined in Stackoverflow and other sources and I can't get any to provide this functionality.

I can get the PDF creation using the Cordova Print PDF plugin and this simple code in index.js, but it's missing the  field data:

`function printPage() {
    var page = location.href;
    cordova.plugins.printer.print(page,'Document.html');
 };`

I've also tried:

`function createPDF() {
    var divToPrint=document.getElementById("this-form");
    pdf.fromData({
            data: divToPrint,
            documentSize: "A4",
            landscape: "portrait",
            type: "share" //use share to open the open-with-menu. 
        }, this.success, this.failure);
 }`

I've got all the code in JSFiddle - though it won't function there since that won't run the cordova app (and cordova.js).

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cgeiser/ty4gocpo/15/

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: edited jsfiddle to make it simpler and easier to read